# Symfony 4 - FOSUserBundle - Render user information on custom route

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I have a constructor and route in my custom ProfileController

```
private $userManager;

public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
{
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
}

/**
 * @Route("/profile/bookings", name="profile_bookings")
 */
public function bookings()
{

    $user = $this->getUser();

    return $this->render('profile/bookings/bookings.html.twig', array('user'=>$user));
}
```

And in my template I reference

{{ user.first_name }}

But I get the error:

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Neither the property "first_name" nor one of the methods "first_name()", "getfirst_name()"/"isfirst_name()"/"hasfirst_name()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\User".

How do I get the user info from db and display in sub pages of profile?

Edit: User Entity ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $profile_height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $profile_weight;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $profile_dob;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, nullable=true)
     */
    private $profile_gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Booking", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $bookings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Overridde setEmail method so that username is now optional
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return parent::setEmail($email);
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName($last_name)
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phone_number): self
    {
        $this->phone_number = $phone_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfileHeight(): ?int
    {
        return $this->profile_height;
    }

    public function setProfileHeight(?int $profile_height): self
    {
        $this->profile_height = $profile_height;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfileDob(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->profile_dob;
    }

    public function setProfileDob(?\DateTimeInterface $profile_dob): self
    {
        $this->profile_dob = $profile_dob;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfileWeight(): ?int
    {
        return $this->profile_weight;
    }

    public function setProfileWeight(?int $profile_weight): self
    {
        $this->profile_weight = $profile_weight;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfileGender(): ?string
    {
        return $this->profile_gender;
    }

    public function setProfileGender(?string $profile_gender): self
    {
        $this->profile_gender = $profile_gender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookings;
    }

    public function addBooking(Booking $booking): self
    {
        if (!$this->bookings->contains($booking)) {
            $this->bookings[] = $booking;
            $booking->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBooking(Booking $booking): self
    {
        if ($this->bookings->contains($booking)) {
            $this->bookings->removeElement($booking);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($booking->getUser() === $this) {
                $booking->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your User entity?

Comment: Yep, just added it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Franck Gamess is right but you can also get rid of the `get`.
If you write `{{ user.firstName }}`, twig will associate that to your method `getFirstName()` automatically.

I don't know why you write your properties with snake_case but you could change it to camelCase and access your properties via their "real" name.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your twig template:

```
{{ user.getFirstName }}
```

It works fine. Normally what Twig does is quite simple on the PHP Layer:

> ```
> check if user is an array and first_name a valid element;
> if not, and if user is an object, check that first_name is a valid property;
> if not, and if user is an object, check that first_name is a valid method (even if first_name is the constructor - use __construct() instead);
> if not, and if user is an object, check that getfirst_name is a valid method;
> if not, and if user is an object, check that isfirst_name is a valid method;
> if not, and if user is an object, check that hasfirst_name is a valid method;
> if not, return a null value.
> ```

See [Twig variables](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables).

By the way you should follow the [Symfony Coding Standard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) for your variable, because it can be difficult for twig to find value of properties written in snake_case.

Comment: Good advice re snake case, thanks. Hang on, so I should be using methods and not variables in my twig?

Comment: If you use variable like my_variable yes, it is easier to access the value like this because you will have to use a strange name for your getters/setters to access this private property in Twig. Or use a variable like myVariable

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should construct the `UserManagerInterface` in your controller. Also, like Franck says, use the coding standard if you can, it will save a lot of time and frustration in the future!

Here is the controller I use in a Symfony 4 project:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * @Route("/profile/bookings", name="profile_bookings")
 */
public function bookings()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->render('profile/bookings/bookings.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not aggree with you when you're saying he should not "construct" the UserManager in the controller. In many case, on my controlle I use some Manager's/service's method so I inject it in the __construct and can access it in the whole controller.

Comment: @Etshy, I thought that since symfony 3.3 you should use dependency injection. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah that's what he's doing with the service type hinting. It inject the Service in the Controller's constructor so it can be used.